# Any performance impact to the order of a compound sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making the following query using flask-sqlalchemy. It works fine both ways, but I'm wondering, as my table grows, if there will be any performance impact to ordering it one way or another:

Option 1:

```
things = Thing.query.filter(Thing.id != 5).order_by(Thing.id.desc()).limit(20).all()
```

Option 2 (order_by and filter are swapped):

```
things = Thing.query.order_by(Thing.id.desc()).filter(Thing.id != 5).limit(20).all()
```

Thank you!

Comment: While on the subject of SQL and order of operations, this is a good read: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While SQL grammar is rather strict about the order of clauses that form a statement, the ORM query builder in SQLAlchemy is generative. It allows adding criteria and options in a more relaxed manner, and before execution it is compiled to produce the final SQL. In this light your two queries result in identical SQL, and so have no performance difference.