# Does the order of slqalchemy commands have an effect on the resulting sql query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Does the order of commands in my sqlalchemy query have an effect on the order of actions in the resulting sql query?

E.g. is this

```
result = db.session.query(Class, Student, SpecialNeed) \
                    .filter(Student.age > 10,
                        Student.class_id == Class.id) \
                    .outerjoin(SpecialNeed, \
                        and_(SpecialNeed.student_id == Student.id , \
                            SpecialNeed.valid == True))
```

the same as this?

```
result = db.session.query(Class, Student, SpecialNeed) \
                    .outerjoin(SpecialNeed, \
                        and_(SpecialNeed.student_id == Student.id , \
                            SpecialNeed.valid == True))\
                    .filter(Student.age > 10,
                        Student.class_id == Class.id)
```

And is this

```
result = db.session.query(Class, Student, SpecialNeed) \
                    .filter(Student.age > 10) \
                    .filter(Student.class_id == Class.id)
```

the same as this?

```
result = db.session.query(Class, Student, SpecialNeed) \
                    .filter(Student.age > 10,
                        Student.class_id == Class.id)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276515/any-performance-impact-to-the-order-of-a-compound-sqlalchemy-query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668752/in-sqlalchemy-is-a-filter-applied-before-or-after-a-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case no, the queries are the same in both cases. The first two are the same [due to how SQL works](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/); first the `FROM` list, then `WHERE`, and so on. SQL just has strict grammar that dictates the order of clauses compared to the [`Query`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) builder pattern in SQLAlchemy. In the latter queries `filter(x, y)` is the same as `filter(x).filter(y)`, both produce `x AND y`.

There are [`Query`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) methods in SQLAlchemy that do depend on the order or have an effect on the order of other operations, such as [`Query.filter_by()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by), and [`Query.from_self()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_self). Also there are operations in SQL [that depend on the order of operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql), such as `LEFT JOIN`.

So the answer to the title is: it can, but not always. You will have to check the documentation and understand what the operation does in addition to understanding the underlying SQL.